# How to control the tiling of a brush stroke in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke, brush

- I have a shape with a stroke
- I selected a brush as the stroke style

Result:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVWGY.png]

I seems like the brush is stretched to fit the whole path. How do I control the "tiling" so that it repeats several times across the path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several types of brushes. An art brush wors like you explained. A scatterbrus scatters many samples across the path, calligraphic brush extrudes a shape over the path.

The brush your looking for is a pattern brush. First you need to create the individual tiles your brush consists of, make patters out of them and then make a brush out of those tiles.

(Alternatively you can just cut your path into n segments)